# How to embedding a link Youtube video in Flutter Web for multiple platforms ( at least for web , window)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used libraries like media_kit, youtube_player_iframe... but the problem is that it uses the form https://xxxxx.mp4 , what I want is that I can embed a youtube link form https://www. youtube.com/watch?v=2Vv-BfVoq4g...

I hope there will be a library that supports youtube video links, I've found a lot but none of them work

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called [**youtube_player_flutter**](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter), here you can find the solution you want.

```
String videoId = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBAyRBTfsOU");

YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
   initialVideoId: videoId,
   flags: YoutubePLayerFlags(
      isLive: true,
   ),
);
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks you but  youtube_player_flutter not support for web and window, I need support for both windows and web

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).